# Multi input model with different dimensions

Tags: python, keras

I would like to do a multi input model for a classification problem. However, I have two input: One with 50 000 rows, and one with 10 000 rows.

The labels are the same, but, obviously, with different sizes. Here is what I did:

```
left_branch = Input((8, ))
left_branch_dense = Dense(5, activation = 'tanh')(left_branch)

right_branch = Input((44350, ))
right_branch_reduc = Dense(100, activation = 'tanh')(right_branch)
right_branch_dense = Dense(5, activation = 'tanh')(right_branch_reduc)
merged = Concatenate()([left_branch_dense, right_branch_dense])
output_layer = Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')(merged)

model = Model(inputs=[left_branch, right_branch], outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([batch_1, batch_2], [labels_bgp_1,labels_bgp_2])
```

However, I have the following error:

Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays

Looks like the model expect only one label array. What should I do??
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Your lable should be in shape of `(batch_size,2)` because you have only one output and as you have assigned here `model = Model(inputs=[left_branch, right_branch], outputs=output_layer)` and you provided two different labels `[labels_bgp_1,labels_bgp_2]` .

Comment: I see ... But how should I do then? I want to merge the weights after training both inputs with both outputs ?? And what is lable ?

Comment: "One with 50 000 rows, and one with 10 000 rows." Do you mean, you have different sized datasets?

Comment: Yes, different sizes but most of all, different features. but They have the same type of labels.
It's like if One dataset had 20 different houses, with 10 features and the price of each of the 20 houses.

And the second dataset has only 10 houses, with 5 totally different features and the price of the 10 houses.


The first idea I had was to merge the two datasets, but as the second dataset has less houses, I would lose a lot of information..